# How to Bubble onMouseMove event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, dom-events, mouseevent

I have image, where I want to show div when I starting to hover on it, but when that div is being hovered React going crazy, because after second div appear image stop his `onMouseMove` event,
State holds variable which will decide if div appear or not. Variable name "zoom"
I want to keep firing `onMouseMove` event even when second div appear, any ideas how I could get something like this?

```html
  <img
    onMouseMove={e => {
      this.setState({ zoom: 'block' });
    }}
    onMouseLeave={() => {
      this.setState({ zoom: 'none' });
    }}
    id="productImg"
    src={images[this.state.imgActive]}
  />
)}
<div
  style={{
    display: this.state.zoom,
    float: 'right',
    overflow: 'hidden',
    zIndex: 100,
    transform: 'translateZ(0px)',
    opacity: '0.4',
    zoom: 1,
    width: 285,
    height: 285,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    border: '1px solrgb(0, 0, 0)',
    backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 0,
    top: 0
  }}
>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seem like you have a `div` on top of the `img`.

When it appears your mouse is on top of the `div` and no more on top of the `img` consequently canceling the event.

I would suggest to add the CSS attribute `pointerEvents: 'none'` to the `div` in order to ignore the mouse events and let them be handled by the element below.

Hope it helps.

Comment: nope, div and img are on same level, they are siblings
but ur idea works! thanks!